# Add class to Accordion Toggle when collapsed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, race-condition, react-bootstrap

In React I have used the 'react-bootstrap' module. When I use Bootstrap accordion to show a list of items. There I need to add a class in "Accordion.Toggle" when "Accordion.Collapse" collapsed. I have tried to do it react onClick function but, it works in every second click as well as previous "Accordion.Toggle" class does not remove when new one collapsed.

N.B: It is possible if I use the Bootstrap CSS and JS directly without Bootstrap node module. Bootstrap provides a class called "collapsed". For reference, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/

[image]

```
class Sidebar extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Accordion>
        <Accordion.Toggle 
          as={Nav.Link} 
          eventKey={1}
          className="HasChild">First Title</Accordion.Toggle>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={1}>
          <Nav as="ul">
            <Nav.Link href="#">First Sub Item</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
          </Nav>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
        <Accordion.Toggle 
          as={Nav.Link} 
          eventKey={2}
          className="HasChild">Second Title</Accordion.Toggle>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={2}>
          <Nav as="ul">
            <Nav.Link href="#">Second Sub Item</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
          </Nav>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
        <Accordion.Toggle 
          as={Nav.Link} 
          eventKey={3}
          className="HasChild">Third Title</Accordion.Toggle>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={3}>
          <Nav as="ul">
            <Nav.Link href="#">Third Sub Item</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
          </Nav>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
      </Accordion>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably sorted this out ages ago, but here's one solution using the React `useState` hook to keep track of which panel is open, and also the `useAccordionToggle` hook from `react-bootstrap` to create a custom Toggle.

It's a slightly different form of writing React code as I prefer function components but it's effectively the same code as yours.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Nav, Accordion, useAccordionToggle } from 'react-bootstrap'

const AccordionClassExample = () => {

  const [panelIndex, setPanelIndex] = useState()

  const CustomToggle = ({ children, eventKey }) => {

    // Decorate the click event to also set state in the component so we can 
    // compare the open panel key with the state and toggle classes accordingly
    const customOnClick = useAccordionToggle(eventKey, () => {
      setPanelIndex( eventKey === panelIndex ? null : eventKey )
    })

    const customClass = (eventKey === panelIndex) ? "open-class" : "closed-class"

    return (
      <Nav.Link className={ customClass } onClick={ customOnClick }>
        { children }
      </Nav.Link>
    )
  }

  return (
    <Accordion>
      <CustomToggle eventKey={ 1 }>First Title</CustomToggle>
      <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={ 1 }>
        <Nav as="ul">
          <Nav.Link href="#">First Sub Item</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Accordion.Collapse>

      <CustomToggle eventKey={ 2 }>Second Title</CustomToggle>
      <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={2}>
        <Nav as="ul">
          <Nav.Link href="#">Second Sub Item</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Accordion.Collapse>

      <CustomToggle eventKey={ 3 }>Third Title</CustomToggle>
      <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={3}>
        <Nav as="ul">
          <Nav.Link href="#">Third Sub Item</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Accordion.Collapse>
    </Accordion>
  )
}

export default AccordionClassExample
```

It's a pretty basic example but hopefully it will help you. It is written in ES6 so hopefully that makes sense to you too.